# Is it Possible to Bind Results using Angular Material like in bootstrap

Tags: angular-material

I need to Bind Array Items to UI.

back in Days i used bootstrap and now looking to use Angular Material.

In bootstrap and angular Binding the code as follows

```
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>{{product.title}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to do the simalar grid binding using Angular Material. I tried below

```
<div layout="column">
        <div ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <md-card>
                <md-card-content>
                  <p>item.title</p>
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Resulting all items in rows. But i need the display to be similar to bootstrap view, showing items next to each other and in next rows

Comment: May be layout="row" ?

Comment: no .....changing from layout="column" to layout="row" wont work.
it just changes the alignment of columns to rows   .....

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add "layout-wrap" attribute to your row.

```
  <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
          <div ng-repeat="item in todos">
              <md-card>
                  <md-card-content>
                    <p>item.title</p>
                  </md-card-content>
              </md-card>
          </div>
   </div>
```

Read more about layout options [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options)